# Finding the best model and taking its information into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as below.

[image]

`p1_conf`,`p2_conf`, and `p3_conf` are respectively showing the confidence interval of model `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`.

I was wondering how I can select the prediction with the highest confidence interval of each row and store it in some new columns. So the result will be as:

[image]

You can use below df as the original df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5],
                "Name": ["Dave","Max","Joe","Rose","Mark"],
                "model1":["Irish","German","USA","Japan","China"],
                "confidence1": [0.9,.99,.83,.45,.51],
                "prediction1": [True,False,True,False,False],
                "model2":["Oman","Nigeria","India","Russia","Brazil"],
                "confidence2": [0.1,.25,.26,.41,.01],
                "prediction2": [False,True,False,False,False],
                "model3":["Egypt","Cameron","Netherland","Canada","Mexcio"],
                "confidence3": [0.01,.23,.12,.34,.61],
                "prediction3": [True,False,True,True,False]})
```

And the outcome should be something like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5],
                 "Name":["Dave","Max","Joe","Rose","Mark"],
                 "model_name":["1","2","1","3",None],
                 "predicted_gener":["Irish","Nigeria","USA","Canada",None],
                 "confidence":[0.9,0.25,.83,0.34,None],
                 "prediction":[True,True,True,True,None]})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you could change your picture to codes that would be better for people to help.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my answer to match the new information you presented. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5],
               "Name": ["Dave","Max","Joe","Rose","Mark"],
               "model1":["Irish","German","USA","Japan","China"],
                "confidence1": [0.9,.99,.83,.45,.51],
                "prediction1": [True,False,True,False,False],
                 "model2":["Oman","Nigeria","India","Russia","Brazil"],
                 "confidence2": [0.1,.25,.26,.41,.01],
                 "prediction2": [False,True,False,False,False],
                 "model3":["Egypt","Cameron","Netherland","Canada","Mexcio"],
                 "confidence3": [0.01,.23,.12,.34,.61],
                 "prediction3": [True,False,True,True,False]})

tweet_id = []
name = []
Model = []
Breed = []
Confidence = []

for i in range(len(df['id'])):
    confidences = [df['confidence{0}'.format(model)][i] for model in range(1,4)]
    models = ['p{0}'.format(model) for model in range(1,4)]
    breeds = [df['model{0}'.format(model)][i] for model in range(1,4)]
    isDog = [df['prediction{0}'.format(model)][i] for model in range(1,4)]

    best_one = max(zip(confidences, models, breeds, isDog), key=lambda M: M[0])

    model = best_one[1]
    breed = best_one[2]
    confidence = best_one[0]

    if not (True in isDog):
        model = breed = confidence = 'NaN'

    tweet_id.append(df['id'][i])
    name.append(df['Name'][i])
    Model.append(model)
    Breed.append(breed)
    Confidence.append(confidence)

print(pd.DataFrame({
                'tweet_id': tweet_id,
                'name': name,
                'Model': Model,
                'Breed': Breed,
                'Confidence': Confidence
                }))
```

Output

```
   tweet_id  name Model   Breed Confidence
0         1  Dave    p1   Irish        0.9
1         2   Max    p1  German       0.99
2         3   Joe    p1     USA       0.83
3         4  Rose    p1   Japan       0.45
4         5  Mark   NaN     NaN        NaN
```

Comment: The code is not completely correct. Besides, would you explain this code: best_one = max(zip(confidences, models, breeds, isDog), key=lambda M: M[0])       @Samy Bencherif

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach,

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5],
                 "Name": ["Dave","Max","Joe","Rose","Mark"],
                 "model1":["Irish","German","USA","Japan","China"],
                 "confidence1": [0.9,.99,.83,.45,.51],
                 "prediction1": [True,False,True,False,False],
                 "model2":["Oman","Nigeria","India","Russia","Brazil"],
                 "confidence2": [0.1,.25,.26,.41,.01],
                 "prediction2": [False,True,False,False,False],
                 "model3":["Egypt","Cameron","Netherland","Canada","Mexcio"],
                 "confidence3": [0.01,.23,.12,.34,.61],
                 "prediction3": [True,False,True,True,False]})
```

---

```
df1 = df.copy()
cols = df1.filter(regex='model').columns

df1[cols] = df1[cols].apply(lambda x: x + "_" + x.index.str[-1], 1)

vals = df1.filter(regex='mod|conf|pred').values.reshape(-1,3,3)

lst = []
for i in vals:
    try:
        lst.append(max([j for j in i if True in j], key=lambda x: x[1]))
    except:
        lst.append([np.nan])

df1 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(lst)).drop(df1.filter(regex='mod|conf|pred'), axis=1)
df1.columns = ['id', 'name', 'predicted_gender', 'confidence', 'prediction']

df1[['predicted_gender','model_name']]= df1['predicted_gender'].str.split('_',expand=True)

print (df1)

   id  name predicted_gender  confidence prediction model_name
0   1  Dave            Irish        0.90       True          1
1   2   Max          Nigeria        0.25       True          2
2   3   Joe              USA        0.83       True          1
3   4  Rose           Canada        0.34       True          3
4   5  Mark              NaN         NaN       None        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will add a new column with max score

```
df['Confidence'] = df[['pf1_conf','pf2_conf','pf3_conf']].max(axis=1)
```

You can than drop those 6 columns.

```
del df['p1','pf1_conf','p2','pf2_conf','p3','pf3_conf']
```